# passing "&" in the url as a value

Tags: php, forms, get, ampersand

i'm working out a search function which submit a standard form, when i'm searching on "&azerty" the url becomes "index.php/search?q=%26azerty"

unfortunately the value of `$_GET['q']` is only `%26amp%3B` and not `%26amp%3Bazerty`

anyone got a clue how i can get access to the complete value of the variable?

Comment: Don't know if you can switch to post but using `$_POST` would solve your problem.

Comment: unfortunately $_POST isn't an option, my boss wants the result to be accessible by URL

Comment: using $_REQUEST instead of $_GET offered a solution...

Answer (score 4):

I believe you are looking for [URL Decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **escape** keyword if doing it with javascript.

obj_win = window.open('testpage.aspx?Parameter1=' + escape(Parameter1) + '&ParentId=testpage', 'new', sFeatures);